# Reactjs loop from a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to understand how to loop through an array from a database using ReactJS. For this particular instance I am using an IndexDB wrapper called [dexie.js](http://dexie.org/).

My React code is below. What I would like it to do is fill out `{this.state.results.name}` with the entire array of stuff that I add to it once I fill out the two boxes and click the submit button.

As is, the code adds the values to the database. I am just having trouble understanding how to use React to query them.

```
var SisterChristian = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
return {results:[{name:'', age:''}]}
},

zanzibar:function(){
var resname = document.getElementById('inputname').value;
var resage = document.getElementById('inputage').value;
var datastoring = new Dexie('MySpace');
datastoring.version(1).stores({
friends: 'name, age'
});

datastoring.open().catch(function(err){
alert('Oh no son:' +err);
});

datastoring.friends.each((friend)=>{
this.setState({results:[{name:resname, age:resage}] });
}); 

datastoring.friends.add({
name: resname, 
age: resage
});
},
render:function(){
return (<div>
<input type="text" id="inputname" />
<input type="text" id="inputage" />
<input type="submit" value="Shipping And Handling" onClick={this.zanzibar}/>
<p>{this.state.results.name}</p>
</div>);}

});

ReactDOM.render(<SisterChristian/>, document.getElementById('bacon'));
```

You can also see it on CodePen, which will hopefully make it easier to see.
http://codepen.io/jasonchenthrow/pen/GqXoyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting mixed up as to what's an array and what's a single object. Here's some general tips.

- indent!!
- To loop over an array and output DOM, use the array method `map` and for item in the array return the required DOM. It's handy (but not necessary) to have a separate function - this keeps your DOM tree inside `render()` easy to read.
- In your example you're saving data to state *and* Dexie, so you must save your new data to state and Dexie. When your app gets more complicated you should save your data to a central store, and pass that store into the component as props.
- If you're typing code that looks up something in the DOM and returns it (e.g. `querySelector`) you're probably thinking the wrong way around. This is brittle (you have to have an ID *and* know that the ID is unique across your entire app) and also this is what `ref`s are for.

Here's the result:

```
var SisterChristian = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return {results:[
      {
        name:'Jason',
        age:'25'
      },
      {
        name:'Bob',
        age:'29'
      }
    ]}
  },

  zanzibar:function(){
    // don't use document.querySelector(), you should be able to access any of your DOM elements like this
    var resname = this.inputNameEl.value;
    var resage = this.inputAgeEl.value;
    var datastoring = new Dexie('MySpace');
    datastoring.version(1).stores({
      friends: 'name, age'
    });

    datastoring.open().catch(function(err){
      alert('Oh no son:' +err);
    });

    // you can't do this, you need to add a new item to the results array, not reset the array
    // datastoring.friends.each((friend)=>{
    //   this.setState({results:[{name:resname, age:resage}] });
    // }); 

    var newFriend = {
      name: resname, 
      age: resage
    };

    datastoring.friends.add(newFriend);

    // this is how you update the state of the object with new data
    var newResults = this.state.results.slice(); // clone the array
    newResults.push(newFriend);
    this.setState({results: newResults});
  },

  renderResults:function(results) {
    return results.map(result => { // this is how you create DOM elements from an array of objects
      return <p key={result.name}>{result.name}, {result.age}</p>;
    });
  },

  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="inputname" ref={el => this.inputNameEl = el} />
        <input type="text" id="inputage" ref={el => this.inputAgeEl = el} />
        <input type="submit" value="Shipping And Handling" onClick={this.zanzibar}/>
        <p>{this.state.results.name}</p>
        <p>{this.renderResults(this.state.results)}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<SisterChristian/>, document.getElementById('bacon'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the `key` value to an ID to get rid of the problem of repeating keys. However, I am left with a remaining problem, which is a `<p> cannot be the descendant of <p>` error. Not sure what to attribute that to.

Comment: I'm guessing you're rendering an li or something, that's an error about HTML structure rather than react specific.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it. Changed the p tags to appropriate ul li. Now I'm trying to understand the key props issue, which apparently cropped up again.

Comment: To add a new `id`, I changed my db to `friends: ++id, name, age`. How would I reorganize `var newFriend` to allow for the new id? I ask as I am still trying to resolve the `each child should have a unique key prop` issue.

Comment: I'd suggest [creating a unique ID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/1976597) when adding the new item, or working out if Dexie can tell you what ID it gave some new item if you do `++id`.